# JsonResults returns Enum value instead of String representation

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, enums

On my Client Side I have an ajax call like below:

```
          $.ajax({
                url: "Controller/ListResult",
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Id: ObjectId,
                    SessionKey: sessionManager.getSessionKey()
                }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                var test = results;
                    }
                }
            });
```

In the Controller I have a method like this :

```
      [HttpPost]
       public JsonResult ListResult(string Id, string SessionKey)
       {
        IBl biz = new BL();
        var result = biz.GetResults(Id,SessionKey);
        return Json(result);
       }
```

The **problem** is the result that controller **returns** is an object which has **Enum** properties (with their string representation as value). However when it reaches the **success** **function** in the ajax call, the enums are no longer string representation, and instead, they have been converted to their **int** values. How can I avoid this? and keep the string representation on the javascript side.

Comment: What is `sessionManager.getSessionKey()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it is an internal function to retrieve session, but this shouldn't affect anything. Because it works as expected.

Comment: You will need to create an anonymous object to represent your data and use  `ToString()` on the enum properties (the `JavascriptSerializer` serializes enums to their numeric values and not their string representation)

Comment: Hi Benjamin , Can you try this one out                                                    return Json(result.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: You can also use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) with the `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` attribute on your properties

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you Stephen. you were totally right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of returning `var result` create some result entity class and you can mark the enum property there with [StringEnumConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm).

```
class Result
{
  [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
  public EnumType EnumProperty { get; set; }

  *****other properties goes here****
}
```

As Stephen suggested this works if one is using `Json.NET` as the serializer.

Comment: Only if OP is using Json.NET as the serializer :)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
    var result = biz.GetResults(Id,SessionKey);
    var modifiedResult = new
      {
        ...,
        r.EnumValue.ToString(),
        ...
      };
    return Json(modifiedResult);
```

Comment: As I said the result in the Controller is already String representation, and there is no need to ToString() it. It just gets converted to int value when it reaches to the Javascript side.

Comment: If the properties in the result getting returned by the Controller are Enums, the call to `return Json(result)` will convert those strings back to their integer values.  If you project the result first into an anonymous type then the properties will just be strings.

Comment: Almost right - but you cannot use `.Select()` on a single object (which is what OP stated the `GetResults()` method returns

Comment: @Stephen -- thanks for the feedback, answer has been updated.